# random crashes with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

I'm running into random crashes where I have no info. When crash Xcode show me this:

[image]

*or this:*

[image]

all connections that depart from the app is run from NSObject class and the code is this:

**.h**

```
@protocol LoadMysqlDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void)loadMysql:(NSArray *)array;
@end

@interface LoadMysql : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) id <LoadMysqlDelegate> delegate;

-(void)connectionMysqlWithNick:(NSString *)nick;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "LoadMysql.h"

@implementation LoadMysql {

    NSMutableArray *_arrayP;
    NSMutableData *_data;    
}

-(void)connectionMysqlWithNick:(NSString *)nick {

    _data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    _arrayP = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

    NSString *stringUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bla.it/load.php?valNick=%@",nick];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringUrl];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:50.0f];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)aResponse
{
    [_data setLength:0];

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {

    [_data appendData:data];
}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {


    id jsonObjects = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

    for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {

        NSString *stringI = [dataDict objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *stringT = [dataDict objectForKey:@"type"];

        NSDictionary *_dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:stringI,@"name",stringT,@"type", nil];

        [_arrayP addObject:_dict];

    }

    [_delegate loadMysql:_arrayP];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];

}

@end
```

the problem may stem from the fact of starting more connection simultaneously?

the majority of connections depart from a background thread

**EDIT**

i've changed:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <LoadMysqlDelegate> delegate;
```

with:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <LoadMysqlDelegate> delegate;
```

but the problem persist.

**EDIT 2**

i finally have the complete stack trace:

[image]

Comment: What is retaining the connection delegate object? What is the full exception message and stack trace?

Comment: @Wain stack trace is not shown, only the code in the pictures I posted

Comment: So what is retaining the delegate? Does pressing the continue button give more info?

Comment: @Wain continue button? .. and sorry but i don't understand what means "what is retaining the delegate" :-/ i think that i don't retain the delegate .. or not? please let explain :) thanks

Comment: The continue button on the debugger. What object is the delegate? What owns it?

Comment: @Wain i declared the delegate in this way: property (nonatomic, strong) id <LoadDelegate> delegate;

Comment: @Wain mmm maybe i should use (nonatomic, weak) ?

Comment: Delegates are usually weak. I don't mean a delegate you define - I mean the object you pass as the delegate of the connection.

Comment: @Wain i edited my question.. you mean the way I call the NSObject class?

Comment: We are still waiting for the complete stacktrace.

Comment: @trojanfoe ok please can you tell me how to get the full stacktrace. because when the app meets this crash I see only the code of the photos that I posted, and I can not do anything, just stop the app and restart it.

Comment: The image fragments you show are from the stacktrace, aren't they?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes but i can see only that code.. or not..?

Comment: There should be a list with the complete call chain.

Comment: @trojanfoe ok.. just will crash again I'll see if I can get the full stacktrace.I do not know when, because the crash is really random

Comment: @trojanfoe i finally post the stack trace